# Replacing the end of a string after the last space

Tags: c#, string, replace, textbox

Is there a way I can replace the last sentence of a string? like the last word after the last space. and replaced it by sending some {SPACE} keys? What I want to do is put the date time of the sentence on the end of the text box, align it to the right

I have not tried any code for this because I cant even think where to start. My objection of what I am trying to do is like Skypes message thing? With the date time on the end.

Is there any tutorials to maybe some list drawitems witch someone said i should use?

Here is skypes:

[image]

Here is mine:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to **replace** the last word, or do you want to **suffix** the string with the date and time? Your question kind of contradicts itself. Even when you don't have code, you could give an example couldn't you?

Comment: I have added some screenshots.

Comment: Its all in one file so i would have to seperate it

Comment: use CSS for the placement of your controls

Comment: Some more information on what you're implementing your UI in would be helpful. ASP.Net? WPF? WinForms? Silverlight? XNA?

Answer (score 0):

You  mentioned replacing the last SENTENCE of a string - and also the last WORD.  Which do you want to do?

To replace the last word in a string, you can do this:

```
var sentence = "scary solution even WITH a monospaced font";
sentence = sentence.Substring(0, sentence.LastIndexOf(' ')) + " CRAZY";
```

However, if you are looking to put a date/time in a specific position relative to some text, adding spaces is a really shockingly bad way to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

See my solution below. It assumes that you are using a multiline text box set
to a monospace font. It uses [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to align/truncate
the username and message to a number of characters determined by the
`userMaxWidth` and `msgMaxWidth` fields. It's quite a clunky solution and
messages are limited to a single line `msgMaxWidth` characters in length. I'd
not recommend this as a serious solution. I would instead look at a custom
control.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ChatForm chatForm = new ChatForm();
            chatForm.PostMessage("Ash", "test",
                DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0));
            chatForm.PostMessage("Bob", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(18, 5, 0));
            Application.Run(chatForm);
        }
    }

    class ChatForm : Form
    {
        public ChatForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int userMaxWidth = 8;
        private int msgMaxWidth = 40;

        public void PostMessage(string user, string msg, DateTime time)
        {
            // Truncate user
            if (user.Length > userMaxWidth)
                user = user.Substring(0, userMaxWidth);
            // Trucate msg
            if (msg.Length > msgMaxWidth)
                msg = msg.Substring(0, msgMaxWidth);
            string compositeString = 
                "#{0,-" + userMaxWidth + "}{1,-" + msgMaxWidth + "}{2:HH:mm}";
            string formattedMsg =
                String.Format(compositeString, user, msg, time);

            textBox.AppendText(formattedMsg);
            textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox
            // 
            this.textBox.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.textBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 8.25F,
                System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.textBox.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox.WordWrap = false;
            this.textBox.Name = "textBox";
            this.textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 200);
            this.textBox.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 200);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
            this.Name = "ChatForm";
            this.Text = "ChatForm";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Text` property of `textBox` is as follows:

```
#Ash     test                                    18:00

#Bob     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 18:05
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't munge up your data with other data for display purposes.

```
string message = "@Bob This is my message                           18:05";
```

That's not something you're going to be able to easily and cleanly implement a display for. You should implement these messages as a class:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

You would then define a view for this structured data using a custom UserControl or an ItemsControl.